# TFVC has several folders with guid names at the org root?

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

Using Azure DevOps Services for source control TFVC. I have an organization with a two projects and repo I'm reviewing for missing files with Team Explorer in VS.

VS Team Explorer => Pending Changes => Detected shows several folders as deleted at the root with guid names that don't correspond to any projects or repos.
They also show using tf.exe. Also, `>tf info <guid>` reports 'No items match'. I'm unable to get or delete.

```
> tf dir
$/:
$D2a0d597a-e6bd-4d98-a5a6-1bb67299c1ec
$D2fb42a09-b859-4fe7-9da9-dc2fe0cdb161
$D446c0411-2c01-4240-aa9a-0622c81d2f98
$D4c43123f-d939-4508-a1f9-d62227544b4a
$D5c8c469d-ffb5-42ad-8633-ba68338d0dd0
$D6a5e225e-3d47-4106-8c02-5bb498a8d632
$D98ad3ed0-99d3-4860-aaca-2c4ac54a3d1a
$Dc5a51173-376b-4477-b971-c6aff6469896
$Dd38db188-783a-46df-bbf0-f894790ec8d2
$Dfb4c160b-f96d-450f-9798-e85257444b0a
$Dev
$MyProject
```

Anyone know what they are?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi there, have you got a chance to check my answer below? May I know if it can resolve your query?

Comment: Thank you. I assumed I could ignore them. They must be local to my workspace since the API url returns count: 0

Comment: Is your account from `PCA` group and you were using the token of this account to call API to list deleted projects? Or maybe the projects were deleted 28 days ago?

Comment: Yes, confirmed I'm the PCA. Also confirmed the same account in the browser for API call and in VS. Can ignore them, NP Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the deleted TFVC projects from your Azure DevOps organization which used to get mapped with the workspaces on this computer. You may have noticed that every GUID begins with `D`.

[image]

Here is the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP#projectstate) you may leverage to get the deleted projects.

```
https://dev.azure.com/{{organization}}/_apis/projects?stateFilter=deleted&api-version=7.1-preview.4
```

[image]